# How do I see which files were repaired by SFC (systems file check)? The CBS.Log doesn't have any details on the name of the files

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, logging, sfc

My Windows 10 crashed during gaming with 0xc000021a BSOD, I decided to ran `sfc /scannow` . It said that it:

> had found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are
> included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

I viewed the raw log file and didn't find any details on what files were corrupt and repaired. I also ran:

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

But all I got was [this](https://pastebin.com/zwZ2pgza).

As you can see there are no details at all. Any ideas?

Comment: A tip for running sfc/scannnow - delete or rename the old log first, then even if you have to sift it by hand, you only have the last session, rather than all of them.

Comment: The PasteBin in now dead. https://pastebin.com/zwZ2pgza

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is unanswered and abandoned as indicated by the dead link to PasteBin. https://pastebin.com/zwZ2pgza